# Expose sub objects through a property

Tags: c#, properties

I'm modeling an API for a client application.  As part of this i'm trying to build a cache that maintains the structure/map of the API as it crawls it (I have to crawl this API, its just that way :(  )

So what I want to do is build a model object like this:

```
 page1
  |
  |__page2
        |
        |_page3
```

So if each page is an object and each object contains a property for child then I can have a repeating set of classes that all look like:

```
public class Page
{
   public Page Child { get; set; }
}
```

So `page1.Child` = `page2`, `page2.Child` = `page3`

On my class where I construct the Cache i'd like to expose the current page like:

```
public class Cache
{
   public Page CurrentPage { get; set; }

   public Cache(){
      //logic to construct cache
   }
   // add, delete Page logic
}
```

So if I load my CurrentPage variable like:
  `cache.CurrentPage = page1.Child.Child`

I'll get a value type copy of the child.  So how do I instead expose the member so that I can operate on the original object instead.  The idea here is that I wan't to be able to work on the current page of the cache without actually having to know where I am in the cache.

Comment: Why do you think that `Page` is a value type?

Comment: You seem to have some inconsistent `Page`/`page` issues here.

Comment: @crashmstr good catch - fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can directly access the value of the child like this.

```
public class Page
    {
        public Page Child { get; set; }
        public string PageNumber { get; set; }
    }
    private static void Main()
    {
        var page1 = new Page {PageNumber = "1"};
        var page2 = new Page {PageNumber = "2"};
        var page3 = new Page {PageNumber = "3"};
        page1.Child = page2;
        page2.Child = page3;

        var x = page1.Child.Child.PageNumber;

        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
```